# How to know the depth value of 24bit depth images in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to deal with 24bit depth images from NYU Hand dataset in MATLAB.

When i tried to read images as below in MATLAB

```
img = imread('synthdepth_1_0006969.png');
```

the form of the variable( img) is 480x640x3 uint8.

My question is, in this case, how do i know the depth value from that?

When I read 8bit or 16bit images in MATLAB, each pixel show the depth value. But

in 24bit case, I don't know how to deal with it...

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the image data is 3 dimensional, with the third dimension having a size of 3. That third dimension encodes the red, green, and blue color planes in a [Truecolor image](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-12468). Three [`uint8`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html) (i.e. unsigned 8-bit integer) color values equates to 24 bits of total color information per pixel.